# No output returned when curl ing any URL in Red Hat 6 but the same url works in lynx browser

Tags: python, curl, iptables, easy-install, lynx

I am trying to install some packages in Python using easy install. But i get a 'Download Error' for any package i try to install. So i tried to test if internet is accessible at all from the machine (Its a Red Hat 6 machine, I am connected remotely) by doing a `$curl www.google.com` . I got no results. But `$lynx www.google.com` brings up the lynx browser with the page opened.

I tried to open ports 80 and 443 using iptables. Still the same error. So if lynx could open the page, it means i have access to the internet. Is there a way to approve specific applications like curl to access the internet. What might be the problem here ?

Comment: You might have better luck on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what is the output of `$ curl -i www.google.com` ?

Comment: @sberry After like a minute i get `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

Comment: Do you have a `.curlrc`, and what happens if you rename that to something else temporarily? Alternitavely, use `curl -q`.

Comment: @Wrikken I tried curl -q www.ggogle.com too. I get the same message. Couldnt connect to host.

Comment: @jgritty Is there a way to import my questions directly across stackexchange sites ? Or will i have to copy paste the whole question there again ?

Comment: I think copy and paste.  You can put a link to this question there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885035